# There is no information about error (asp net mvc 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, debugging, iis-8

I have developed a website using ASP.NET MVC 3. The site works well on a local development server. I deployed site on the hosting using the publishing feature in visual studio 2010. When I launched [the site](http://vac.somee.com), I saw a white screen.

**Web.config**

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <compilation debug="True" targetFramework="4.0">
       .....
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Interestingly, the migration work correctly. In the database, all tables are created.

How to enable output of error information? I would be glad to any advice.

Comment: Are you sure that when you deployed your application customErrors is still set to `Off`? This doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, Now I deleted all the files from the host. Then I downloaded the new files from the local computer and deployed a new application. You can see my file Web.config: http://pastebin.com/JxAYjnW2